# python urllib2 and ntlm - getting '<h1>Object Moved</h1>' in response html

Tags: python, http, urllib2, ntlm

I am using ntlm to access an internal server that uses windows authentication. The url that I am trying to access keeps redirecting. Here is my code:

```
import urllib2
from ntlm import HTTPNtlmAuthHandler
import cookielib

user = r'Domain\username'
password = "password"

url = r"http://cmsll.jvservices.com/Livelink/"

passman = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
passman.add_password(None, url, user, password)
# create the NTLM authentication handler
auth_NTLM = HTTPNtlmAuthHandler.HTTPNtlmAuthHandler(passman, debuglevel=1)

cookieJar = cookielib.CookieJar()

# create and install the opener
opener = urllib2.build_opener(auth_NTLM, urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookieJar))
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

url = r"http://cmsll.jvservices.com/Livelink/livelink.exe?func=ll&objId=87167&objAction=runReport&inputLabel1_ID=118163&inputLabel1_Name=%22Lastname%2C+Firstname+%28domain\username%29%22&inputLabel2=D%2F2013%2F5%2F21%3A0%3A0%3A0&inputLabel2_dirtyFlag=1&inputLabel2_month=5&inputLabel2_day=21&inputLabel2_year=2013&inputLabel2_hour=13&inputLabel2_minute=53&inputLabel2_second=0&inputLabel2_ampm=0&inputLabel3=D%2F2014%2F5%2F21%3A0%3A0%3A0&inputLabel3_dirtyFlag=0&inputLabel3_month=5&inputLabel3_day=21&inputLabel3_year=2014&inputLabel3_hour=0&inputLabel3_minute=0&inputLabel3_second=0&inputLabel3_ampm=0>"

# retrieve the result
req = urllib2.Request(url)
req.add_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:29.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0 FirePHP/0.7.4')

response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
print(response.read())
```

Here is the output:

```
send: 'GET /Livelink/livelink.exe?func=ll&objId=87167&objAction=runReport&inputLabel1_ID=118163&inputLabel1_Name=%22Lastname%2C+Firstname+%28domain\\username%29%22&inputLabel2=D%2F2013%2F5%2F21%3A0%3A0%3A0&inputLabel2_dirtyFlag=1&inputLabel2_month=5&inputLabel2_day=21&inputLabel2_year=2013&inputLabel2_hour=13&inputLabel2_minute=53&inputLabel2_second=0&inputLabel2_ampm=0&inputLabel3=D%2F2014%2F5%2F21%3A0%3A0%3A0&inputLabel3_dirtyFlag=0&inputLabel3_month=5&inputLabel3_day=21&inputLabel3_year=2014&inputLabel3_hour=0&inputLabel3_minute=0&inputLabel3_second=0&inputLabel3_ampm=0 HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept-Encoding: identity\r\nHost: cmsll.jvservices.com\r\nConnection: Keep-Alive\r\nAuthorization: <stuff here>\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:29.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0 FirePHP/0.7.4\r\n\r\n'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized\r\n'
header: Content-Length: 1539
header: Content-Type: text/html
header: Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
header: WWW-Authenticate: <stuff here>
header: X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
header: Date: Thu, 22 May 2014 14:16:38 GMT
send: 'GET /Livelink/livelink.exe?func=ll&objId=87167&objAction=runReport&inputLabel1_ID=118163&inputLabel1_Name=%22Lastname%2C+Firstname+%28domain\\username%29%22&inputLabel2=D%2F2013%2F5%2F21%3A0%3A0%3A0&inputLabel2_dirtyFlag=1&inputLabel2_month=5&inputLabel2_day=21&inputLabel2_year=2013&inputLabel2_hour=13&inputLabel2_minute=53&inputLabel2_second=0&inputLabel2_ampm=0&inputLabel3=D%2F2014%2F5%2F21%3A0%3A0%3A0&inputLabel3_dirtyFlag=0&inputLabel3_month=5&inputLabel3_day=21&inputLabel3_year=2014&inputLabel3_hour=0&inputLabel3_minute=0&inputLabel3_second=0&inputLabel3_ampm=0 HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept-Encoding: identity\r\nHost: cmsll.jvservices.com\r\nConnection: Close\r\nAuthorization: <stuff here>\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:29.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0 FirePHP/0.7.4\r\n\r\n'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 302 Redirect\r\n'
header: Content-Length: 895
header: Content-Type: text/html
header: Expires: -1
header: Location: http://cmsll.jvservices.com/Livelink/livelink.exe?func=ll.GetTZ&NextURL=%2FLivelink%2Flivelink%2Eexe%3Ffunc%3Dll%26objId%3D87167%26objAction%3DrunReport%26inputLabel1_ID%3D118163%26inputLabel1_Name%3D%2522Lastname%252C%2BFirstname%2B%2528domain%5Cu370471%2529%2522%26inputLabel2%3DD%252F2013%252F5%252F21%253A0%253A0%253A0%26inputLabel2_dirtyFlag%3D1%26inputLabel2_month%3D5%26inputLabel2_day%3D21%26inputLabel2_year%3D2013%26inputLabel2_hour%3D13%26inputLabel2_minute%3D53%26inputLabel2_second%3D0%26inputLabel2_ampm%3D0%26inputLabel3%3DD%252F2014%252F5%252F21%253A0%253A0%253A0%26inputLabel3_dirtyFlag%3D0%26inputLabel3_month%3D5%26inputLabel3_day%3D21%26inputLabel3_year%3D2014%26inputLabel3_hour%3D0%26inputLabel3_minute%3D0%26inputLabel3_second%3D0%26inputLabel3_ampm%3D0
header: Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
header: X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
header: Date: Thu, 22 May 2014 14:16:39 GMT
header: Connection: close
<head><title>Document Moved</title></head>
<body><h1>Object Moved</h1>This document may be found <a HREF="http://cmsll.jvservices.com/Livelink/livelink.exe?func=ll.GetTZ&amp;NextURL=%2FLivelink%2Flivelink%2Eexe%3Ffunc%3Dll%26objId%3D87167%26objAction%3DrunReport%26inputLabel1_ID%3D118163%26inputLabel1_Name%3D%2522Lastname%252C%2BFirstname%2B%2528domain%5Cu370471%2529%2522%26inputLabel2%3DD%252F2013%252F5%252F21%253A0%253A0%253A0%26inputLabel2_dirtyFlag%3D1%26inputLabel2_month%3D5%26inputLabel2_day%3D21%26inputLabel2_year%3D2013%26inputLabel2_hour%3D13%26inputLabel2_minute%3D53%26inputLabel2_second%3D0%26inputLabel2_ampm%3D0%26inputLabel3%3DD%252F2014%252F5%252F21%253A0%253A0%253A0%26inputLabel3_dirtyFlag%3D0%26inputLabel3_month%3D5%26inputLabel3_day%3D21%26inputLabel3_year%3D2014%26inputLabel3_hour%3D0%26inputLabel3_minute%3D0%26inputLabel3_second%3D0%26inputLabel3_ampm%3D0">here</a></body>
```

The response html isn't what I'm looking for. I have tried following this redirect manually, and it gives me another redirect. What am I doing to cause it to redirect like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably due to you having the "offset time zone" setting in the Admin pages.  "GetTZ" means "Get Time Zone".  To stop it, uncheck the box in "Modify Date and Times" on each server/installation instance.  It's not a system-wide setting.